# Get clean machine-friendly Maven lines/xml/json output parseable by scripts in STDOUT?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

For example, run this command with for a maven project:

```
mvn dependency:list
```

What I need from Maven is *only* these two lines (cut out from the output below):

```
com.example.code_samples.maven_dependencies:direct_library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
com.example.code_samples.maven_dependencies:indirect_library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

**Is there a way (CLI `--option`) to see only this requested info in clean lines, xml, json, ...?**

Instead, the output looks more like an unstructured log. It has no known format and mixes all types of information together in STDOUT.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] direct_library
[INFO] dependent_binary
[INFO] indirect_library
[INFO] maven_dependencies
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building direct_library 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/code_samples/maven_dependencies/indirect_library/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/code_samples/maven_dependencies/indirect_library/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 16.1
 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ direct_library ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.4:test
[INFO]    com.example.code_samples.maven_dependencies:indirect_library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building dependent_binary 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/code_samples/maven_dependencies/direct_library/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/example/code_samples/maven_dependencies/direct_library/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 86.2 K
B/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ dependent_binary ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.example.code_samples.maven_dependencies:direct_library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    com.example.code_samples.maven_dependencies:indirect_library:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building indirect_library 3.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ indirect_library ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    none
[INFO] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven_dependencies 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ maven_dependencies ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    none
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] direct_library ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.813 s]
[INFO] dependent_binary ................................... SUCCESS [  0.026 s]
[INFO] indirect_library ................................... SUCCESS [  0.013 s]
[INFO] maven_dependencies ................................. SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.065 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-24T12:10:01+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/607M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, I would accept solution to use Maven API to get runtime data like `Collection<String>` (instead of the text output like above which cannot be parsed reliably).

I took a look at [Maven Invoker API](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html), but I don't have hope - my tests showed that it's just a way to invoke Maven from code. And these APIs return no runtime data (just error code with all useful information printed in logs again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to supply a property to save required clean output into a file.

For example, [-DoutputFile](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-mojo.html#outputFile) or [-Doutput](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html#output):

```
mvn dependency:list     -DoutputFile=dependencies.output.txt
mvn help:effective-pom  -Doutput=effective.pom.xml
```

If STDOUT is required, `cat` the file.

Even though it's not generic, so far, the workaround solves all cases for me.

Comment: Please note that the Help Plugin suffers from a severe bug: [MPH-87](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPH-87)

Answer (score 3):

Maven uses standard slf4j logging, wrapped in a plexus container. https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

You should be able to configure the slf4j bindings to provide different output formats as detailed here http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#log4jXMLLayout

I'm not familiar with the cleanlines and json logging formats; however, slf4j is probably one of the more adaptable logging packages, so look around for a Formatter and you have a chance at finding one.  However, if you don't the last link above also covers the pages on how to write your own logging layout.

Comment: Keep in mind that Maven supports sub-calls of Maven.  This means that whatever logging you intend to parse should be done by a parser that can understand when a run is nested within another run.  Otherwise it will only work "most of the time".

Comment: The problem is that I want to parse as little as possible (i.e. pass output to a xml/json/etc. parsing library). Even if I remove all [INFO] prefixes, the calls to logging library are the Maven way to produce results, and all other information will still be mixed in because the same calls to log are used for everything else. It's actually quite stupid of Maven not to differentiate execution logs (which should go to STDERR by default) and the requested clean output on STDOUT which should comply with at least some format declared by Maven target and contain nothing but the expected results.

Comment: In its core, the issue is that Maven is not designed for this. Changing log output format won't change what goes to the log output. If I could switch off everything except (as in example) just list of dependencies, it would solve the problem. But logs can only leveled up/down or reformatted. So, I find your answer helpful (voting up), but I won't accept it as the issue remains (possibly forever).

Comment: slf4j can suppress (or enhance) logging by turning down (or up) that logger level.  The format can be altered overall, or altered in part.  The only issue is that you cannot actually change the logging message in slf4j configurations.  I have used it to provide XML formatted output, so I would imagine that you could too.  The fact that this is logging done by maven is not really as important as you think, slf4j doesn't handle logging differently because of a different product using its libraries

Comment: FYI, if it may help, I've found a workaround - see accepted answer.